# Puppet - Multiple nodes syntax

Tags: manifest, nodes, puppet

I am actually running a Puppet 2.7x setup to benchmark its capabilities using a group of test servers.

My actual `site.pp` :

```
node 'devnode' inherits 'deploy' {
    include 'server1.test.com'
    include 'server2.test.com'
    include 'server3.test.com'
    include 'server4.test.com'
}

node 'deploy' {
    include motd
    include ssh
    include ntp
}
```

doesn't work as intended (meaning: the `motd`, `ssh` and `ntp` modules are not applied to the nodes `serverN.test.com` located within the `devnode` node).

I previously had the following `site.pp` :

```
node /^server[1-4]\.test\.com$/ {
    include motd
    include ssh
    include ntp
}
```

but it lacks flexibility when I want to test a specific module on a single node.

Considering the following :

1. I do not want to use an ENC yet (I am still in the process of learning Puppet basics)
2. I'd like to keep this Puppet version (v2.7x) for logistic reasons inside my company
3. the example given (`serverN.test.com`) doesn't unfortunately reflect the name of my
   company servers (whom all have 'unique' names with very little to no
   possibility for a regex to work, except maybe on the domaine
   `test.com`)
4. I'd prefer to display all the nodes name (in `devnode`) to facilitate 
   the inclusion/exclusion of nodes for the administrators

what are my options ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot formulate a regex, that is unfortunate. If the `test.com` domain is sufficient for your needs, you should use

```
node /.*\.test\.com$/ { ... }
```

instead of `devnode` (which makes little sense anyway, because it is only matched by agents whose unqualified names *is* "devnode").

If your `fqdn`s are that chaotic, you may benefit from an [ENC](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html) such as [Foreman](http://theforeman.org/) or the web interface of Puppet Enterprise after all. Such a classifier allows you to link classes to nodes flexibly. The `hiera_include` function will make [Hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/) a simplistic ENC even.

An option that forgos the ENC idea is of course to enumerate your `fqdn`s in `nodes.pp`, perhaps introducing another inheritance layer.

```
node fqdn1.test.com inherits devnode { ... }
node fqdn2.test.com inherits devnode { ... }
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Felix. I am reading the link about Hiera, which seems to be the easiest and/or simpliest way to implement an ENC. I realize it is quite hard to have a different config for a set of nodes and, at the same time, keeping all your nodes as homogeneous as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to specify couple node names per definition in site.pp :

```
node 'www1.example.com', 'www2.example.com', 'www3.example.com' { 
    include common 
    include apache, squid
}
```

Disclaimer: Not sure that this feature available in Puppet 2.7